# Email template id is not found issue in magento 2 admin custom form Magento 2

Tags: email, custom, email-templates, magento2.4.4

I Want to send a url to customer from admin panel custom form.
I use below steps to perform the task.

1 - `email_templates.xml` file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="ayakil_hometry_email_carturl_template" label="Home Try On Cart Url" file="hometry_cart_url.html" type="html" module="Ayakil_HomeTry" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

2 - `hometry_cart_url.html` (**app/code/Ayakil/HomeTry/view/adminhtml/email/hometry_cart_url.html**) file content

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Home Try On Cart Email!"}} @-->
<!--{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}-->
<p class="greeting">Dear {{var name}}</p>
<p>
Please find the Url <a href="{{var carturl}}" target="_blank"> HERE </a> to proceed with your order.</p>
<!--{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}-->
```

3 - Controller file `Email.php`(**Path app/code/Ayakil/HomeTry/Controller/Save.php**)

```
....
try {
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('ayakil_hometry_email_carturl_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML,
                'store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            ])
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $templateVars])
            ->setFrom([
                'email' => $this->config->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/email'),
                'name' => $this->config->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/name')
            ])
            ->addTo($email, $name)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

    } catch (MailException $mailException) {
        throw new $mailException->getMessage();
    }
}
...
```

I am getting the following error after save the form.

> template hometry_cart_url.html not found.

I can view and load the newly created email template from admin panel `Marketting->Email Template -> load templates`
Can anyone please help me to find my issue or suggest me a best way to do this task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you just defined area frontend but you setup your template to adminhtml.

Simple move the file to frontend, or change the area code to adminhtml.

Comment: i have define the are as adminhtml only, Mistakenly updated the question with frontend